# Problem involving an infinite lattice grid

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I'm stuck on this problem for Intro to Point-Set Topology.... I'm given that a submarine starts somewhere in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and moves in a straight line at constant velocity, in such a way that at every hour it is at a point whose coordinates are integers. At every hour, I am able to drop one bomb at one point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose coordinates are integers. My task is to show that I can drop bombs in such a way that I will eventually hit the submarine.

My work so far:
I know that $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is countable, and since the set of integer-lattice points intersected by the submarine is a subset of $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$, this set is also countable.

I also know I can parametrize the path of the submarine as follows, where $k_1, k_2, m_1, m_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $m_1, m_2 \neq 0$.
\begin{align*}
x & = k_1 + m_1 t \\
y & = k_2 + m_2 t
\end{align*}
where $t$ is the time in hours.

I also can come up with ways to count all of $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$, and hence the path of the submarine. For example, I could start at $(0,0)$, then go to $(0,1)$, then $(-1,1)$, then $(-1,0)$, then $(-1, -1)$, then $(0,-1)$, and continue in a sort of square spiral. I know that this spiral will eventually hit every point on the path of the submarine as time goes to infinity. But...how do I guarantee that I actually hit the submarine itself???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to hit every *point*, focus of hitting every possible combination of *starting points* and *velocities* of the submarine. There are only countably many $(k_1,k_2,m_1,m_2)\in\mathbb Z^4$ to check, so you can go through them all in sequence. For each combination, drop a bomb at the point the sub will have reached by now *if those parameters are right*.